# Stream chunks of video

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

When playing large videos in an axshockwave control how can I stream chunks of a video so the ram doesn't get too full. I am trying to stream a video in C# winforms without using IIS

This is the code i'm using to stream an entire video at once but if it is to large the application freezes.

```
 using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
 {
      using (BinaryWriter br = new BinaryWriter(ms))
      {
           br.Write(8 + file.Length);
           br.Write(0x55665566);
           br.Write(file.Length);
           br.Write(file);
           ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
           flashPlayer.OcxState = new AxHost.State(ms, 1, false, null);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Do you have an idea about why it freezes? It shouldn't

Comment: It only freezes if the video is larger than 1 gig. I think it is freezing because I dont have 1 gig of RAM available to store the stream

Comment: My guess is that it is not freezing but the operation is taking a long time. Could it be?

Comment: If I leave it, after a few minutes windows error pops saying program is not responding, do you want to wait or close.                                                                                                            Even if it is just taking a long time, I still need to stream in chunks to make it faster